# Is it possible to animate a rigid object while it's running its physics course?

Tags: animation, physics

I was planning to create an animation of a rubiks cube, which will be a set of rigid cubes with core locking the parts together like a real rubiks cube, solving itself as it is resting on the floor, so whenever it flips one of the 3x3 planes it will jump around if the flipping pushes itself from the ground up. So you would have a rubiks cube that jumps around as it's flipping sides. Is that even possible?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Do you want precise animation or less than precise animation?   You may consider an armature of 2 bones or so.  For less than precise animation rotation might suffice barely.

Comment: wow that sounds interesting, can you be so kind and show me a simple working example of a precise animation using bones? maybe a cube is enough resting on the floor and animate it to rotate on the X or Y whose force will push it upwards strong or weak depending how strong the rotational force animation applied? that'd be really helpful

Comment: Perhaps related to gear animation.

Comment: I may or may not have time for more.  Animation currently baking.  Is the rotation face of Rubiks Cube RK causing the whole cube to move or not?

Comment: yeah the rotation animation demonstrated on the right side of my image will cause the whole cube to move like in the real world. so if the animation is slow it will slowly tilt cube while if the rotation animation is quick it would cause it to slightly bounce up. so the tilt or intensity of the bounce would depend on the speed of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Modifier and Driver information]

**Armature Technique**

The armature rotates the cube on either the left edge or right edge.

[image: Armature Heirarchy and Parent information]

---

Armature of 2 Bones is present. Copy rotation constraint is present.  Single line driver is present.
Bone.002 is the parent . See image.  The other bone has the same modifier and the inverse of the driver condition.  This activates rotation in one bone or the other.

---

Above you see a two bone armatures replicated for illustrative purposes.  A box floor is present and a cube rotated which pierce thes  floor just as sources of rotation. Rotation about the Y global axis in negative - and positive +.  Rotation + and - shows edge switching.  In rest position the two bones are antiparallel and coincident. Both bones are equal in length to the width dimension of a cube.  Bone name Bone.002 is the object parent of the entire cube.  The somewhat coincident bones are similar to some foot rigs allowing toe heel hell switching. We assume one edge of the cube is always placed exactly on the floor plane.  Please excuse the view of edge occluded by armature structure.  Z axis adjustment can be added easily if bounce or jump is needed.  Tested for ∠a : -Π/2 < a <  Π/2.

Edits to follow

Comment: OP was asking about animating an object that is a rigid body in a physics simulation, in a way that the set animation interferes with the physics simulation.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati yes. i think it is not possible.